# Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.fromXML(String)" because "this.xstream" is null

Tags: spring, spring-batch

I am getting below error in Spring Batch Read from XML and Write to DB.

Error

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.fromXML(String)" because "this.xstream" is null
    at org.springframework.batch.core.repository.dao.XStreamExecutionContextStringSerializer.deserialize(XStreamExecutionContextStringSerializer.java:120) ~[spring-batch-core-4.3.4.jar:4.3.4]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.repository.dao.XStreamExecutionContextStringSerializer.deserialize(XStreamExecutionContextStringSerializer.java:49) ~[spring-batch-core-4.3.4.jar:4.3.4]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.repository.dao.JdbcExecutionContextDao$ExecutionContextRowMapper.mapRow(JdbcExecutionContextDao.java:325) ~[spring-batch-core-4.3.4.jar:4.3.4]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.repository.dao.JdbcExecutionContextDao$ExecutionContextRowMapper.mapRow(JdbcExecutionContextDao.java:312) ~[spring-batch-core-4.3.4.jar:4.3.4]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.RowMapperResultSetExtractor.extractData(RowMapperResultSetExtractor.java:94) ~[spring-jdbc-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.RowMapperResultSetExtractor.extractData(RowMapperResultSetExtractor.java:61) ~[spring-jdbc-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate$1.doInPreparedStatement(JdbcTemplate.java:723) ~[spring-jdbc-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:651) ~[spring-jdbc-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:713) ~[spring-jdbc-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:744) ~[spring-jdbc-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:757) ~[spring-jdbc-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:815) ~[spring-jdbc-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.repository.dao.JdbcExecutionContextDao.getExecutionContext(JdbcExecutionContextDao.java:114) ~[spring-batch-core-4.3.4.jar:4.3.4]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.repository.support.SimpleJobRepository.getLastJobExecution(SimpleJobRepository.java:276) ~[spring-batch-core-4.3.4.jar:4.3.4]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:64) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:344) ~[spring-aop-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:198) ~[spring-aop-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163) ~[spring-aop-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:123) ~[spring-tx-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:388) ~[spring-tx-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:119) ~[spring-tx-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:215) ~[spring-aop-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy77.getLastJobExecution(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:64) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:344) ~[spring-aop-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:198) ~[spring-aop-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163) ~[spring-aop-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.SimpleBatchConfiguration$PassthruAdvice.invoke(SimpleBatchConfiguration.java:128) ~[spring-batch-core-4.3.4.jar:4.3.4]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:215) ~[spring-aop-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy77.getLastJobExecution(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.batch.JobLauncherApplicationRunner.getNextJobParametersForExisting(JobLauncherApplicationRunner.java:218) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.6.1.jar:2.6.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.batch.JobLauncherApplicationRunner.getNextJobParameters(JobLauncherApplicationRunner.java:207) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.6.1.jar:2.6.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.batch.JobLauncherApplicationRunner.execute(JobLauncherApplicationRunner.java:198) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.6.1.jar:2.6.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.batch.JobLauncherApplicationRunner.executeLocalJobs(JobLauncherApplicationRunner.java:173) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.6.1.jar:2.6.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.batch.JobLauncherApplicationRunner.launchJobFromProperties(JobLauncherApplicationRunner.java:160) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.6.1.jar:2.6.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.batch.JobLauncherApplicationRunner.run(JobLauncherApplicationRunner.java:155) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.6.1.jar:2.6.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.batch.JobLauncherApplicationRunner.run(JobLauncherApplicationRunner.java:150) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.6.1.jar:2.6.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:758) ~[spring-boot-2.6.1.jar:2.6.1]
    ... 5 common frames omitted
```

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.1</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>readingXML</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <name>readingXML</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
        <maven-jar-plugin.version>3.1.1</maven-jar-plugin.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- Spring Starter Batch -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-batch</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Spring OXM -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-oxm</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring Starter JDBC -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- H2 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- MYSQL -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- XSTREAM -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.thoughtworks.xstream</groupId>
            <artifactId>xstream</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.18</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Lombok -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.batch</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-batch-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

JobConfiguration.java

```
package com.example.config;

import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.springframework.batch.core.Job;
import org.springframework.batch.core.Step;
import org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.BatchConfigurer;
import org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.DefaultBatchConfigurer;
import org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.JobBuilderFactory;
import org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.StepBuilderFactory;
import org.springframework.batch.core.repository.JobRepository;
import org.springframework.batch.core.repository.dao.XStreamExecutionContextStringSerializer;
import org.springframework.batch.core.repository.support.JobRepositoryFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.batch.item.ItemWriter;
import org.springframework.batch.item.database.ItemPreparedStatementSetter;
import org.springframework.batch.item.database.JdbcBatchItemWriter;
import org.springframework.batch.item.xml.StaxEventItemReader;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource;
import org.springframework.oxm.xstream.XStreamMarshaller;

import com.example.domain.Customer;
import org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager;

@Configuration
public class JobConfiguration {
    @Autowired
    private JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory;
    
    @Autowired
    private StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory;
    
    @Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource;

    @Bean
    BatchConfigurer configurer(@Qualifier("dataSource") DataSource dataSource, PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager) {
        return new DefaultBatchConfigurer(dataSource) {
            @Override
            protected JobRepository createJobRepository() throws Exception {
                JobRepositoryFactoryBean factory = new JobRepositoryFactoryBean();
                factory.setDataSource(dataSource);
                factory.setTransactionManager(transactionManager);
                factory.setSerializer(new XStreamExecutionContextStringSerializer());
                factory.afterPropertiesSet();
                return factory.getObject();
            }
        };
    }
    
    @Bean
    public StaxEventItemReader<Customer> customerItemReader(){
        Map<String, Class> aliases = new HashMap<>();
        aliases.put("customer", Customer.class);
        
        CustomerConverter converter = new CustomerConverter();
        XStreamMarshaller ummarshaller = new XStreamMarshaller();
        ummarshaller.setAliases(aliases);
        ummarshaller.setConverters(converter);
        
        StaxEventItemReader<Customer> reader = new StaxEventItemReader<>();
        reader.setResource(new ClassPathResource("/data/customer.xml"));
        reader.setFragmentRootElementName("customer");
        reader.setUnmarshaller(ummarshaller);
        
        return reader;
    }
    
    @Bean
    public Step step1() {
        return stepBuilderFactory.get("step1")
                .<Customer, Customer>chunk(200)
                .reader(customerItemReader())
                .writer(writer())
                .build();
    }
    
    @Bean
    public Job job() {
        return jobBuilderFactory.get("job")
                .start(step1())
                .build();
    }
    
    @Bean
    public JdbcBatchItemWriter<Customer> writer() {
        JdbcBatchItemWriter<Customer> writer = new JdbcBatchItemWriter<>();
        writer.setDataSource(this.dataSource);
        writer.setSql("INSERT INTO customer (id, birthdate, first_name, last_name) VALUES (?,?,?,?)");
        writer.setItemPreparedStatementSetter(new CustomerItemPreparedStmSetter());
        return writer;
    }
    
    private  class CustomerItemPreparedStmSetter implements ItemPreparedStatementSetter<Customer> {

        public void setValues(Customer result, PreparedStatement ps) throws SQLException {
            ps.setLong(1, result.getId());
            ps.setDate(2, java.sql.Date.valueOf( result.getBirthdate() ));
            ps.setString(3, result.getFirstName());
            ps.setString(4, result.getLastName());
        }
    }
}
```

@As per suggestion from **@M. Deinum**, created below bean

```
@Bean
    public XStreamMarshaller getXStreamMarshaller() {
        XStreamMarshaller xstreamMarshaller = new XStreamMarshaller();
        xstreamMarshaller.setTypePermissions(AnyTypePermission.ANY);
        xstreamMarshaller.setSupportedClasses(Customer.class);
        return xstreamMarshaller;
    }
```

and now getting below error.

```
org.springframework.oxm.UnmarshallingFailureException: XStream unmarshalling exception; nested exception is com.thoughtworks.xstream.security.ForbiddenClassException: com.example.domain.Customer
    at org.springframework.oxm.xstream.XStreamMarshaller.convertXStreamException(XStreamMarshaller.java:877) ~[spring-oxm-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.oxm.xstream.XStreamMarshaller.doUnmarshal(XStreamMarshaller.java:855) ~[spring-oxm-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.oxm.xstream.XStreamMarshaller.unmarshalXmlStreamReader(XStreamMarshaller.java:812) ~[spring-oxm-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.oxm.xstream.XStreamMarshaller.unmarshalXmlEventReader(XStreamMarshaller.java:803) ~[spring-oxm-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.oxm.support.AbstractMarshaller.unmarshalStaxSource(AbstractMarshaller.java:412) ~[spring-oxm-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.oxm.support.AbstractMarshaller.unmarshal(AbstractMarshaller.java:355) ~[spring-oxm-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.batch.item.xml.StaxEventItemReader.doRead(StaxEventItemReader.java:273) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-4.3.4.jar:4.3.4]
    at org.springframework.batch.item.support.AbstractItemCountingItemStreamItemReader.read(AbstractItemCountingItemStreamItemReader.java:93) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-4.3.4.jar:4.3.4]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProvider.doRead(SimpleChunkProvider.java:99) ~[spring-batch-core-4.3.4.jar:4.3.4]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProvider.read(SimpleChunkProvider.java:180) ~[spring-batch-core-4.3.4.jar:4.3.4]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProvider$1.doInIteration(SimpleChunkProvider.java:126) ~[spring-batch-core-4.3.4.jar:4.3.4]
    at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.getNextResult(RepeatTemplate.java:375) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-4.3.4.jar:4.3.4]
    at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.executeInternal(RepeatTemplate.java:215) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-4.3.4.jar:4.3.4]
    at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.iterate(RepeatTemplate.java:145) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-4.3.4.jar:4.3.4]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProvider.provide(SimpleChunkProvider.java:118) ~[spring-batch-core-4.3.4.jar:4.3.4]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.ChunkOrientedTasklet.execute(ChunkOrientedTasklet.java:71) ~[spring-batch-core-4.3.4.jar:4.3.4]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$ChunkTransactionCallback.doInTransaction(TaskletStep.java:407) ~[spring-batch-core-4.3.4.jar:4.3.4]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$ChunkTransactionCallback.doInTransaction(TaskletStep.java:331) ~[spring-batch-core-4.3.4.jar:4.3.4]
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionTemplate.java:140) ~[spring-tx-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$2.doInChunkContext(TaskletStep.java:273) ~[spring-batch-core-4.3.4.jar:4.3.4]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.scope.context.StepContextRepeatCallback.doInIteration(StepContextRepeatCallback.java:82) ~[spring-batch-core-4.3.4.jar:4.3.4]
    at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.getNextResult(RepeatTemplate.java:375) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-4.3.4.jar:4.3.4]
    at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.executeInternal(RepeatTemplate.java:215) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-4.3.4.jar:4.3.4]
    at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.iterate(RepeatTemplate.java:145) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-4.3.4.jar:4.3.4]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep.doExecute(TaskletStep.java:258) ~[spring-batch-core-4.3.4.jar:4.3.4]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.AbstractStep.execute(AbstractStep.java:208) ~[spring-batch-core-4.3.4.jar:4.3.4]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.SimpleStepHandler.handleStep(SimpleStepHandler.java:152) ~[spring-batch-core-4.3.4.jar:4.3.4]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.AbstractJob.handleStep(AbstractJob.java:413) ~[spring-batch-core-4.3.4.jar:4.3.4]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.SimpleJob.doExecute(SimpleJob.java:136) ~[spring-batch-core-4.3.4.jar:4.3.4]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.AbstractJob.execute(AbstractJob.java:320) ~[spring-batch-core-4.3.4.jar:4.3.4]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher$1.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:149) ~[spring-batch-core-4.3.4.jar:4.3.4]
    at org.springframework.core.task.SyncTaskExecutor.execute(SyncTaskExecutor.java:50) ~[spring-core-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:140) ~[spring-batch-core-4.3.4.jar:4.3.4]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:64) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:344) ~[spring-aop-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:198) ~[spring-aop-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163) ~[spring-aop-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.SimpleBatchConfiguration$PassthruAdvice.invoke(SimpleBatchConfiguration.java:128) ~[spring-batch-core-4.3.4.jar:4.3.4]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:215) ~[spring-aop-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy69.run(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.batch.JobLauncherApplicationRunner.execute(JobLauncherApplicationRunner.java:199) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.6.1.jar:2.6.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.batch.JobLauncherApplicationRunner.executeLocalJobs(JobLauncherApplicationRunner.java:173) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.6.1.jar:2.6.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.batch.JobLauncherApplicationRunner.launchJobFromProperties(JobLauncherApplicationRunner.java:160) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.6.1.jar:2.6.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.batch.JobLauncherApplicationRunner.run(JobLauncherApplicationRunner.java:155) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.6.1.jar:2.6.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.batch.JobLauncherApplicationRunner.run(JobLauncherApplicationRunner.java:150) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.6.1.jar:2.6.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:758) ~[spring-boot-2.6.1.jar:2.6.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunners(SpringApplication.java:748) ~[spring-boot-2.6.1.jar:2.6.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:309) ~[spring-boot-2.6.1.jar:2.6.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1301) ~[spring-boot-2.6.1.jar:2.6.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1290) ~[spring-boot-2.6.1.jar:2.6.1]
    at com.example.ReadingXmlApplication.main(ReadingXmlApplication.java:12) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: com.thoughtworks.xstream.security.ForbiddenClassException: com.example.domain.Customer
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.security.NoTypePermission.allows(NoTypePermission.java:26) ~[xstream-1.4.18.jar:1.4.18]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.SecurityMapper.realClass(SecurityMapper.java:74) ~[xstream-1.4.18.jar:1.4.18]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:125) ~[xstream-1.4.18.jar:1.4.18]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.CachingMapper.realClass(CachingMapper.java:47) ~[xstream-1.4.18.jar:1.4.18]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.util.HierarchicalStreams.readClassType(HierarchicalStreams.java:29) ~[xstream-1.4.18.jar:1.4.18]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.start(TreeUnmarshaller.java:133) ~[xstream-1.4.18.jar:1.4.18]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractTreeMarshallingStrategy.unmarshal(AbstractTreeMarshallingStrategy.java:32) ~[xstream-1.4.18.jar:1.4.18]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.unmarshal(XStream.java:1391) ~[xstream-1.4.18.jar:1.4.18]
    at org.springframework.oxm.xstream.XStreamMarshaller.doUnmarshal(XStreamMarshaller.java:852) ~[spring-oxm-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    ... 53 common frames omitted
```

sample.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<customers>
    <customer>
        <id>1</id>
        <firstName>John</firstName>
        <lastName>Doe</lastName>
        <birthdate>10-10-1988 19:43:23</birthdate>
    </customer>
    <customer>
        <id>2</id>
        <firstName>James</firstName>
        <lastName>Moss</lastName>
        <birthdate>01-04-1991 10:20:23</birthdate>
    </customer>
    ....
    ....
</customers>
```

Customer.java

```
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Builder
@Data
@XStreamAlias("customer")
public class Customer {
    private Long id;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private LocalDate birthdate;
}
```

CustomerService.java

```
public class CustomerConverter implements Converter {
    private static final DateTimeFormatter DT_FORMATTER = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss");
    
    @Override
    public boolean canConvert(Class type) {
        return type.equals(Customer.class);
    }

    @Override
    public void marshal(Object source, HierarchicalStreamWriter writer, MarshallingContext context) {
        // Don't do anything
    }

    @Override
    public Object unmarshal(HierarchicalStreamReader reader, UnmarshallingContext context) {
        reader.moveDown();
        Customer customer = new Customer();
        customer.setId(Long.valueOf(reader.getValue()));
        
        reader.moveUp();
        reader.moveDown();
        customer.setFirstName(reader.getValue());
        
        reader.moveUp();
        reader.moveDown();
        customer.setLastName(reader.getValue());
        
        reader.moveUp();
        reader.moveDown();
        customer.setBirthdate(LocalDate.parse(reader.getValue(), DT_FORMATTER));
        
        return customer;
    }

}
```

Comment: Make the `XSStreamMarshaller` a bean so that the proper callback methods are called. Currently it is only created and not properly initialized.

Comment: @M.Deinum - Still no luck, added new error getting because of new bean, also added more code for better clarity.

Comment: Which is a totally different question which already has been answered here on stackoverflow.

Comment: I am also facing the same issue. Does anyone knows the solution? Code snippet from code perspective is expected

Answer (score 3):

I was able to solve this issue just by adding below

```
ummarshaller.setTypePermissions(AnyTypePermission.ANY);
```

Below is the code for your reference:

```
package com.example.config;

import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import org.springframework.batch.core.Job;
import org.springframework.batch.core.Step;
import org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.JobBuilderFactory;
import org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.StepBuilderFactory;
import org.springframework.batch.item.xml.StaxEventItemReader;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource;
import org.springframework.oxm.xstream.XStreamMarshaller;

import com.example.domain.Customer;
import com.example.writer.CustomerWriter;
import com.thoughtworks.xstream.security.AnyTypePermission;

@Configuration
public class JobConfiguration {
    @Autowired
    private JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory;
    
    @Autowired
    private StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory;
    
    

    @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
    @Bean
    public StaxEventItemReader<Customer> customerItemReader(){
        Map<String, Class> aliases = new HashMap<>();
        aliases.put("customer", Customer.class);
        aliases.put("id", Long.class);
        aliases.put("firstName", String.class);
        aliases.put("lastName", String.class);
        aliases.put("name", String.class);
        aliases.put("birthdate",LocalDate.class);
        
        CustomerConverter converter = new CustomerConverter();

        XStreamMarshaller ummarshaller = new XStreamMarshaller();
        ummarshaller.setAliases(aliases);
        ummarshaller.setConverters(converter);
        ummarshaller.setTypePermissions(AnyTypePermission.ANY);
        
        StaxEventItemReader<Customer> reader = new StaxEventItemReader<>();
        reader.setResource(new ClassPathResource("/data/customer.xml"));
        reader.setFragmentRootElementName("customer");
        reader.setUnmarshaller(ummarshaller);
        
        return reader;
    }
    
    @Bean
    public CustomerWriter customerWriter() {
        return new CustomerWriter();
    }
    
    @Bean
    public Step step1() throws Exception {
        return stepBuilderFactory.get("step1")
                .<Customer, Customer>chunk(200)
                .reader(customerItemReader())
                .writer(customerWriter())
                .build();
    }
    
    @Bean
    public Job job() throws Exception {
        return jobBuilderFactory.get("job")
                .start(step1())
                .build();
    }
}
```

[image]

[image]